# Not able to connect to Secured Channel when doing SFTP with JSch

Tags: java, exception, sftp, jsch

I am trying to implement JSch to retrieve a file from remote windows sftp server to Linux.

```
Session session = null;
    Channel channel = null;
    ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;
        try{
           JSch jsch = new JSch();
           session = jsch.getSession("userName","hostName",22);
           session.setPassword("password");
           java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
           config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
          session.setConfig(config);
          session.connect();
          System.out.println(session.sendKeepAliveMsg());
          channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
          channel.connect();
         }catch(Exception e){
               e.printstacktrace();
         }
```

I am getting following exception while running this code.

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.io.IOException: inputstream is closed
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.start(ChannelSftp.java:288)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Channel.connect(Channel.java:152)
```

When I debug I found:

```
start();
```

method in **Channel class** is throwing the exception. Is there anyway I can prevent this? I don't understand why the method is there without doing nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to cast your channel into ChannelSft before the connect:

```
Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
ChannelSftp channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
channelSftp.connect();
```

Comment: Hey I apologize to mark it as fixed......I fixed it long time ago .. thanks for the answer though

Comment: I got same problem. I've investigation from 2 aspects; 1. as with happening of the exception, meawhile I found my application sent TCP packet with Reset flat set(which probably indicates there is some problem over the session) 2. My application was implemented is exactly the same the symptomatic one above. My doubt is that in respect of exception stack trace, the start() method of ChannelSftp was called eventually, so what is the exact reason of casting channel object to ChannelSftp before calling connect() method.      Thank you guys for any hint

Comment: @Quintus.Zhou It wouldn't make any difference whether it is casted or not.  The implementation does not change.  I'm getting the same problem, and I get it regardless of whether or not it is casted prior in any case.