# com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.io.IOException: Pipe closed

Tags: java, sftp

I am trying to copy a file over SFTP to another Host using Jcraft JSch (http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/). I am getting below error:

```
Connecting via SSH to somehost:22
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.io.IOException: Pipe closed
at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.start(ChannelSftp.java:315)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Channel.connect(Channel.java:152)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Channel.connect(Channel.java:145)
```

Relevant code is below:

```
Channel channel = null;
    ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;
    Exception cause = null;
    try {
      connect();
      channel = session.openChannel( "sftp" );
      channelSftp = (ChannelSftp)channel;
      channelSftp.connect();
      assert channelSftp != null;
      try {
        channelSftp.ls( destDir );
      } catch( SftpException sftpEx ) {
        // Create destination folder, if it does not exist
        execCommand( "some command" + destDir );
      }
```

This was all good since last week, upgrading to latest jcraft version doesn't work. I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13057638/not-able-to-connect-to-secured-channel-when-doing-sftp-with-jsch) and [this](http://tech.forums.softwareag.com/techjforum/posts/list/57435.page) (refer last comment on page), but could not reach to root cause. Any help?

Comment: Have you checked the network? Tried a telnet or ssh in command line?

Comment: Sure, I lost access to the environment. I will reproduce the issue and update. I also feel it to be network/host issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSH was working without any issue. Problem was with SFTP module path in SSH config. Below link was not accessible.

```
# override default of no subsystems 
Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

Comment: Thank you very much kind sir! My directory was set to ../ssh/... but it needed to be ../openssh/..