# SFTP Java - Pipe closed Jsch Exception

Tags: java, authentication, mule, sftp, jsch

I am working on a java method to copy files from one location to another remote location. My code is as follows. I tried using **jsch 0.1.42 & 0.1.50 & 0.1.54**

```
      public static void processFiles(ArrayList<String> FilesToBeCopied, String destFilePath) throws IOException {
        SftpClient client = new SftpClient("karthick");
        String keyFilePath = "/ab/c/d/id_rsa";
        String sftpUser = "karthickkb";
        client.login(sftpUser, keyFilePath, null);
        client.changeWorkingDirectory(destFilePath);
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        FSDataInputStream fsdisPath = null;
        String filePath = null;
        for (String sourcefilePath : FilesToBeCopied) {
            try {
                filePath = sourcefilePath;
                Path inputPath = new Path(filePath);
                fsdisPath = fs.open(inputPath);
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fsdisPath);
                client.storeFile(inputPath.getName(), bis);
                fsdisPath.close();
                fsdisPath = null;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (client != null) {
                        client.disconnect();


        }
                if (fsdisPath != null) {
                    fsdisPath.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}

}
```

Error code when I used Jsch 0.1.42 is 
The following error code I received when I used jsch 0.1.42.

```
     java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Pipe closed
    at org.mule.transport.sftp.SftpClient.storeFile(SftpClient.java:390)
    at karthickArchive.archiveMigration.sftpFileUtil.processFiles(sftpFileUtil.java:58)
    at karthickArchive.archiveMigration.getFileUtility.main  (getFileUtility.java:69)

     17/08/14 07:06:41 ERROR sftp.SftpClient: Error writing data over SFTP service, error was: java.io.IOException: Pipe closed
    4: java.io.IOException: Pipe closed
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._put(ChannelSftp.java:578)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:439)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.put(ChannelSftp.java:406)
    at org.mule.transport.sftp.SftpClient.storeFile(SftpClient.java:385)
    at karthickArchive.archiveMigration.sftpFileUtil.processFiles(sftpFileUtil.java:58)
    at karthickArchive.archiveMigration.getFileUtility.main(getFileUtility.java:69)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Pipe closed
    at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:308)
    at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:378)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.fill(ChannelSftp.java:2325)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.header(ChannelSftp.java:2351)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._put(ChannelSftp.java:474)
    ... 5 mor
```

when I use jsch 0.1.50, the error as follows

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: identities
    at com.jcraft.jsch.UserAuthPublicKey.start(UserAuthPublicKey.java:39)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:463)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
```

I tried to explore enough and I couldn't get a clear answer for my problem and I guess I am missing something. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Maven Dependency tree when I use **jsch 0.1.50**

```
 [INFO] Scanning for projects...
 [INFO]                                                                         
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] Building archiveMigration 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ archiveMigration ---
 [INFO] tdiArchive:archiveMigration:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
 [INFO] +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-hdfs:jar:2.5.0-cdh5.3.2:compile
 [INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:11.0.2:compile
 [INFO] |  |  \- (com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.26.cloudera.4:compile
 [INFO] |  |  \- (org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.26.cloudera.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.26.cloudera.4:compile
 [INFO] |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.9:compile
 [INFO] |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.9:compile
 [INFO] |  |  +- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
 [INFO] |  |  \- (com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.9:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile
 [INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4:compile
 [INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
 [INFO] |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
 [INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
 [INFO] |  +- commons-daemon:commons-daemon:jar:1.0.13:compile
 [INFO] |  +- javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1:compile
 [INFO] |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
 [INFO] |  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.5.0:compile
 [INFO] |  +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:compile
 [INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.8.8:compile
 [INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.8.8:compile
 [INFO] |  |  \- (org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.8.8:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  +- tomcat:jasper-runtime:jar:5.5.23:compile
 [INFO] |  |  +- (javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.4:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.5)
 [INFO] |  |  \- commons-el:commons-el:jar:1.0:compile
 [INFO] |  |     \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.3:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1.3)
 [INFO] |  +- xmlenc:xmlenc:jar:0.52:compile
 [INFO] |  \- io.netty:netty:jar:3.6.2.Final:compile
 [INFO] +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:jar:2.5.0-cdh5.3.2:compile
 [INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-annotations:jar:2.5.0-cdh5.3.2:compile
 [INFO] |  |  \- jdk.tools:jdk.tools:jar:1.6:system
 [INFO] |  +- (com.google.guava:guava:jar:11.0.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  +- (commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.1.1:compile
 [INFO] |  +- (xmlenc:xmlenc:jar:0.52:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
 [INFO] |  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.0.4:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1.3)
 [INFO] |  |  \- (commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.2:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.4)
 [INFO] |  +- (commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  +- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.1:compile
 [INFO] |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
 [INFO] |  +- (javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  +- (org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.26.cloudera.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  +- (org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.26.cloudera.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  +- (com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.9:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:jar:1.9:compile
 [INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.1:compile
 [INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.3-1:compile
 [INFO] |  |  |  \- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.2:compile
 [INFO] |  |  |     +- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
 [INFO] |  |  |     \- (javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1-osgi)
 [INFO] |  |  +- (org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.8.3:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.8.8)
 [INFO] |  |  +- (org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.8.3:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.8.8)
 [INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.8.3:compile
 [INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.8.3:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.8.8)
 [INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.8.3:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.8.8)
 [INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.8.3:compile
 [INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.8.3:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.8.8)
 [INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.8.3:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.8.8)
 [INFO] |  |  \- (com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.9:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  +- (com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.9:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  +- tomcat:jasper-compiler:jar:5.5.23:runtime
 [INFO] |  +- (tomcat:jasper-runtime:jar:5.5.23:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  +- (javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  +- (commons-el:commons-el:jar:1.0:compile - scope updated from runtime; omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  +- (log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  +- net.java.dev.jets3t:jets3t:jar:0.9.0:compile
 [INFO] |  |  +- (commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1.3)
 [INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.1.2:compile
 [INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.1.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.1.2:compile
 [INFO] |  |  \- com.jamesmurty.utils:java-xmlbuilder:jar:0.4:compile
 [INFO] |  +- (commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.6:compile
 [INFO] |  |  +- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  |  +- (commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.6)
 [INFO] |  |  +- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1.3)
 [INFO] |  |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8:compile
 [INFO] |  |  |  +- (commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.8.0)
 [INFO] |  |  |  \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1.3)
 [INFO] |  |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.8.0:compile
 [INFO] |  |     \- (commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.1.3)
 [INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile
 [INFO] |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.5:compile - scope updated from runtime; omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  +- (org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.8.8:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  +- (org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.8.8:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  +- org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.7.6-cdh5.3.2:compile
 [INFO] |  |  +- (org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.8.8)
 [INFO] |  |  +- (org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.8.8)
 [INFO] |  |  +- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.3:compile
 [INFO] |  |  +- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.0.5:compile
 [INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.4.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.4:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.5)
 [INFO] |  +- (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.5.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.4:compile
 [INFO] |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-auth:jar:2.5.0-cdh5.3.2:compile
 [INFO] |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  |  +- (commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  |  +- (log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.5:runtime - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.2.5:compile - omitted for conflict with 4.1.2)
 [INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.directory.server:apacheds-kerberos-codec:jar:2.0.0-M15:compile
 [INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.directory.server:apacheds-i18n:jar:2.0.0-M15:compile
 [INFO] |  |  |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.directory.api:api-asn1-api:jar:1.0.0-M20:compile
 [INFO] |  |  |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.directory.api:api-util:jar:1.0.0-M20:compile
 [INFO] |  |  |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.5-cdh5.3.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.curator:curator-framework:jar:2.6.0:compile
 [INFO] |  |     +- (org.apache.curator:curator-client:jar:2.6.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  |     +- (org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.6:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.4.5-cdh5.3.2)
 [INFO] |  |     \- (com.google.guava:guava:jar:16.0.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 11.0.2)
 [INFO] |  +- (com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.42:compile - omitted for conflict with 0.1.50)
 [INFO] |  +- org.apache.curator:curator-client:jar:2.6.0:compile
 [INFO] |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.6:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.5)
 [INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.6:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.4.5-cdh5.3.2)
 [INFO] |  |  \- (com.google.guava:guava:jar:16.0.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 11.0.2)
 [INFO] |  +- org.apache.curator:curator-recipes:jar:2.6.0:compile
 [INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.curator:curator-framework:jar:2.6.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  |  +- (org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.6:compile - omitted for conflict with 3.4.5-cdh5.3.2)
 [INFO] |  |  \- (com.google.guava:guava:jar:16.0.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 11.0.2)
 [INFO] |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
 [INFO] |  +- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.5-cdh5.3.2:compile
 [INFO] |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.5:compile
 [INFO] |  |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  |  |  \- (log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  |  \- (log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.4.1:compile
 [INFO] |     \- org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.0:compile
 [INFO] +- org.mule.transports:mule-transport-sftp:jar:3.4.0:compile
 [INFO] |  +- (com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.44-1:compile - omitted for conflict with 0.1.42)
 [INFO] |  +- org.mule:mule-core:jar:3.4.0:compile
 [INFO] |  |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0:compile
 [INFO] |  |  +- org.safehaus.jug:jug:jar:asl:2.0.0:compile
 [INFO] |  |  +- (commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  |  +- (commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  |  +- (commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.4:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.4)
 [INFO] |  |  +- (commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.6)
 [INFO] |  |  +- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.5.3:compile
 [INFO] |  |  +- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1-osgi:compile
 [INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
 [INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-j2ee-connector_1.5_spec:jar:1.1-osgi:compile
 [INFO] |  |  +- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:jar:1.0:compile
 [INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
 [INFO] |  |  |  \- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.5)
 [INFO] |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.5)
 [INFO] |  |  +- (org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.7.5)
 [INFO] |  |  +- (log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.2.17)
 [INFO] |  |  +- (asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  |  +- asm:asm-commons:jar:3.1:compile
 [INFO] |  |  |  \- asm:asm-tree:jar:3.1:compile
 [INFO] |  |  |     \- (asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |  |  +- org.mvel:mvel2:jar:2.1.3.Final:compile
 [INFO] |  |  +- org.jgrapht:jgrapht-jdk1.5:jar:0.7.3:compile
 [INFO] |  |  \- org.mule.common:mule-common:jar:0.11.0:compile
 [INFO] |  \- (org.mule.transports:mule-transport-file:jar:3.4.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] +- org.mule.transports:mule-transport-file:jar:3.4.0:compile
 [INFO] |  \- org.mule.modules:mule-module-spring-config:jar:3.4.0:compile
 [INFO] |     +- (org.mule:mule-core:jar:3.4.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |     +- org.mule.modules:mule-module-annotations:jar:3.4.0:compile
 [INFO] |     |  +- (org.mule:mule-core:jar:3.4.0:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |     |  \- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.2:compile
 [INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] |     |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] |     |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |     |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] |     |  |  +- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |     |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |     |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] |     |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
 [INFO] |     |  \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.1.RELEASE:compile
 [INFO] |     +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1-osgi:compile
 [INFO] |     \- jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1.1:compile
 [INFO] |        +- (jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1-beta-6:compile - omitted for cycle)
 [INFO] |        +- (dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile - omitted for conflict with 1.6.1-osgi)
 [INFO] |        +- (jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.0-FCS:compile - omitted for cycle)
 [INFO] |        \- jdom:jdom:jar:1.0:compile
 [INFO] \- com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.50:compile
 [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
 [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 [INFO] Total time: 7.989 s
 [INFO] Finished at: 2017-08-14T18:02:29+05:30
 [INFO] Final Memory: 18M/356M
 [INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------------      ----
```

After removing all the other JSCH libraries and the following is my maven and I don't see any other JSCH library other than **0.1.50**

I still the error in the line

> client.login(sftpUser, keyFilePath, null);

```
 Actual Log:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: identities
    at com.jcraft.jsch.UserAuthPublicKey.start(UserAuthPublicKey.java:39)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:463)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
    at org.mule.transport.sftp.SftpClient.login(SftpClient.java:178)
    at karthickArchive.archiveMigration.sftpFileUtil.processFiles(sftpFileUtil.java:46)
    at karthickArchive.archiveMigration.getFileUtility.main(getFileUtility.java:69)
```

Comment: `NoSuchFieldError` when using JSch 0.1.50 is probably caused by another part of your application still using another JSch version. Are you sure you re-compiled your entire code? I.e. `Normally, this error is caught by the compiler; this error can only occur at run time if the definition of a class has incompatibly changed.` 

With JSch 0.1.42, which line exactly is throwing the exception? (showing the entire stacktrace might help)

Comment: @PierreB  THanks for the comment. I have edited the complete stack strace when I used jsch 01.42 and I see that error occurs in the line client.storeFile(inputPath.getName(), bis); .  thanks much for the suggestion.

Comment: @PierreB. I did a mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose in the project (using jsch 0.1.50) and I found that the project and I have added all the logs in the original post: Particularly this  :  +- org.mule.transports:mule-transport-sftp:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- (com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.44-1:compile - omitted for conflict with 0.1.42)

+- (com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.42:compile - omitted for conflict with 0.1.50)

[INFO] \- com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.50:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS

Comment: Ok thanks for the details. Not directly related to your problem, why are you using Mule SFTP client? As far as I know, this client should be used as part of a Mule application and is not intended to be used in a standalone Java application. (edit: saying this as you may encounter other issues caused by side effects of running these piece of code out of context. Take a look as the source Mule SftpClient source code, it depends on Mule Core elements which may not play well with your code)

Comment: The thing I want to copy a file from HDFS file system to other machine. Which requires the Hadoop file system conf to set and stream the files from HDFS to copy it to local. I tried jsch channel but that connects directly to sftp and does a put operation which doesn't connect to HDFS system. That's the whole reason here. mule sftp is the best solution on this behalf.

Comment: Mule SftpClient uses JSch internally, so in fact you are using JSch in both cases ;-) Looking at the source code it seems the error is caused by some JSch internal InputStream instance to be closed when calling storeFile()... I don't know why, it may be an issue with JSch and HDFS. Try to use a more recent version of the Mule SftpClient (it seems you are using 3.4, as of today 3.8 is the most recent release and it uses JSch 0.1.51)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at your code a second time (right after my coffee, it's better), `java.io.IOException: Pipe closed` with JSch 0.1.42 is  effectively caused by a logic issue as you suggested:

Your finally block is *inside* your for loop. As a finally block is always called whether an exception occur or not your client is always disconnected by the finally block at the end of the very first iteraton:

```
for(...){
    try{
        ...
    }catch(...){
        ...
    }finally{
        # this finally block is inside your for loop
        # finally block is always called whether an exception occur or not
        # on the first iteration, this is called and close your client
        try{
            if(client!=null){
                # nope, it will close the client for next iteration!
                client.disconnect();
            }if(fsdisPath!=null){
                # good to close this however
                fsdisPath.close();
            }
        }catch(Exceptionex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Instead you should have something like:

```
try {
    for(...){
        try{
            ...
        }catch(...){
            ...
        }finally{
            try{
                if(fsdisPath!=null){
                    fsdisPath.close();
                }
            }catch(Exceptionex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
} finally {
    if(client!=null){
        client.disconnect();
    }
}
```

It may also be a good idea to have your for loop as a function for code visibility ;)

`java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: identities` is caused by another part of your application using a different JSch version as you put into evidence per your Maven dependency tree.

> did a mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose in the project (using jsch 0.1.50) and I found that the project and I have added all the logs in the original post: Particularly this : +- org.mule.transports:mule-transport-sftp:jar:3.4.0:compile [INFO] | +- (com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.44-1:compile - omitted for conflict with 0.1.42) +- (com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.42:compile - omitted for conflict with 0.1.50) [INFO] - com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.50:compile [INFO]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a server issue. Are you sure the user you are connecting with has write acces? Is your SFTP server accessible otherwise? Take a look at this post: [com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.io.IOException: Pipe closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42714133/com-jcraft-jsch-jschexception-java-io-ioexception-pipe-closed)

Also check the your ssh server logs you may have something useful there.

Comment: When I passed a list of small files using jsch 0.1.42..No issues in the server side . the first file is transferred to other machine. Issue is from the second file onwards. does this mean any logical issue in the code that connection is closed abruptly before processing ?

Comment: You're right, taking a second look at your code it seems to be a logic issue. I posted an appropriate answer.